# How many down-votes does it take to lower your reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I have been looking at [the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and the parts about reputation and voting, but I was wondering how many down-votes does it take to lower your reputation?

Maybe I have just not been looking in the right place, and if I have not I would appreciate someone pointing me to the information.

Comment: Do you mean giving, or receiving down-votes? Either way: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Comment: Receiving down-votes, such as getting -6 on a question that was poorly worded.

Comment: The duplicate has all the relevant details about reputation.  Check it out =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Receiving downvotes:**

- in answers gives you `-2`
- in questions gives you `-2`

**Casting downvotes:**

- in answers gives you `-1`
- in questions doesn't affect your rep

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Downvoting:

- Free on questions.
- Costs `1` rep on answers.

Receiving downvotes:

- Subtracts `2` rep on questions and answers.

  Keep in mind that you cannot have a reputation lower than `1`, so if you're already at `1`, receiving downvotes doesn't change your reputation.

See also: [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)